# Частный реверт изменений Eclipse с svn

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoise-svn, git-svn

Имеется проект, над которым работаю. Среда разработки - Eclipse. Проект под svn.

Перед коммитом кода, для ч**а**ст**н**ых откатов (кусками) удобно передвигаться по отдельным изменениям, ревертя сразу "кусок на кусок" при необходимости.
До этого работал под винду, там под черепахой (tortoise svn) такой функционал реализован (переход альт+стрелка вниз, реверт кода - альт+стрелка направо). Сейчас сижу на линуксе, к этой фиче привык, неудобно без нее. Есть частное мнение, что такой функционал есть в эклипс, но как его включить/какой плагин поставить для включения?

Comment: Начнём сначала: что в Eclipse стоит для SVN? Что там в настройках?

Comment: А как определить, что там стоит?
З.Ы. Пока обхожусь костылем: по нфс подмонтировал к машине на линуксе нужную папку,там запустил виртуалку - винду и в ней юзаю тортойз свн